# Where is the 'display post information on' settings?

Tags: 7, nodes

I've seen [the discussion](http://drupal.org/node/138958) of this setting, which I gather used to be under theming.

They discuss it being moved to content type, which makes a lot of sense; going through content types in my install, I don't see any option similar to this. Where is it in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under "Structure > Content Types > *your content type*  > edit > Display > Settings."

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It's under the the tab 'Display settings' of the edit page of your content type; for Article this is on `admin/structure/types/manage/article/edit`: Display author and date information.